# How to give the option to change the Textbloack foreground-color,size in Windowsphone7

Tags: silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7.1

I am completely new in Windowsphone7.i have develop sample application in that i want give the option to change the font-color,Size,style(Italic/Bold) as Dynamically(like RadEditor) .please help me how to resolve this option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you Develop your Application MVVM style then it is not so hard to do this. You just need a property for every setting you want to set dynamically and then bind to this properties. And you create a Settings View where you can set the properties  and if you change them you use INotifyPropertyChanged to broadcast that your properties value changed and so every control which is bound to that property will change and redraw.

[GalaSoft MVVM](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/)

[MVVM Codeplex](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/)

[Easy MVVM sample Application for Windows Phone 7](http://www.labo-dotnet.com/post/Creating-your-first-MVVM-silverlight-application-on-windows-phone-7.aspx)

The link you found to save an image looks ok, but i did it a bit different, actually from the CameraCaptureTask you already get a WritableBitmap Image and you can save it like this.

To save the Image:

```
private void SaveToIsolatedStorage(WriteableBitmap image, string fileName)
{
    using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        if (myIsolatedStorage.FileExists(fileName))
        {
            myIsolatedStorage.DeleteFile(fileName);
        }

        using (var stream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        Extensions.SaveJpeg(image, stream, image.PixelWidth, image.PixelHeight,0, 100);
                    }
    }
}
```

To read the Image:

```
private WritableBitmap ReadFromIsolatedStorage(string fileName)
{
    WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(200,200);
    using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        if (store.FileExists(fileName))
                    {
                        using (var stream = store.OpenFile(fileName,FileMode.Open))
                        {
                          bitmap.SetSource(stream);

}}                 
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

I hope this will work because i wrote it from scratch. :)

And in your ViewModel you should have a WritableBitmap Property which is bound to your Image Control on your View.

To use a lot of images and work with them you should read a bit more about this, because somehow SL Images use a lot of memory so you will need to address this problem somehow in the future.

Comment: Just edited and added a few links with examples to help you start with MVVM and your problem. :)

Comment: Hi i have one more question that is i have capture the picture from mobile cam and this picture i want show in another Xmal file after page navigate ..is it possible please help me..

Comment: i have try using this link http://windowsphonegeek.com/tips/All-about-WP7-Isolated-Storage---Read-and-Save-Captured-Image   But i did not get image into another Xmal page .

Comment: Yes it is possible and i did that too, or better said used it too. The link explains how you save the image into IsolatedStorage of your application and you can retrieve this image later too. But if you only need it once then i think it would be better to have a property for your image in your ViewModel and then retrieve it from there.

Comment: Updated my answer hopefully it will work for you or you will have a code to start from.